# Time-span aggregation on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, time-series, aggregation-framework, timespan

Let there be a MongoDB collection `Data` that holds the history of temperatures of some items. So the items are like this:

```
{
  "itemId" : "ABCD",
  "timePoint" : NumberLong("1618922410288"),
  "temperature" : 15.15
}
```

meaning, that the item `"ABCD"` had a temperature `15.15` at `1618922410288ms` since the epoch.

What is the query that will result in the history of some span-average temperatures of the given item starting from the given time point?

So e.g. for `itemId="ABCD", span=60*60*1000, startingTimePoint=0` it has to be a query that will result to the hourly-avarage temperatures of `"ABCD"` starting throm `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

I would also like the query not to be "welded" with the average, but rather accept an arbitrary aggregation function, so it will be easy to use the same technique for `avg`, `min`, `max`, or something else. But this is the second question.

Comment: You can start with querying the data using the [Comparison Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#comparison).

Comment: Did you try to use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ stage?